# java.io.EOFException: Short read of block. When scanning a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github, bitbucket

I have a Jenkins box set up with a few different projects inside it, all of which run fine except this one. Below is the full error message, any help would be much appreciated.

[Tue Feb 27 10:30:53 UTC 2018] Starting branch indexing...

> git --version # timeout=10

using GIT_SSH to set credentials

> git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:ShopDirect/galleryproductservice.git # timeout=10
>
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10

Setting origin to git@bitbucket.org:ShopDirect/galleryproductservice.git

> git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:ShopDirect/galleryproductservice.git # timeout=10

Fetching & pruning origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin

> git --version # timeout=10

using GIT_SSH to set credentials

> git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune

Listing remote references...

> git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
>   using GIT_SSH to set credentials
>
> git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:ShopDirect/galleryproductservice.git # timeout=10

Checking branches...
  Checking branch master

ERROR: [Tue Feb 27 10:30:56 UTC 2018] Could not fetch branches from source 4f8abeb4-bbc0-4de0-bf74-9b2c3cf1cb71

java.io.EOFException: Short read of block.

```
at org.eclipse.jgit.util.IO.readFully(IO.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.UnpackedObject.open(UnpackedObject.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openLooseObject(ObjectDirectory.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openLooseFromSelfOrAlternate(ObjectDirectory.java:403)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openObject(ObjectDirectory.java:385)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.CanonicalTreeParser.reset(CanonicalTreeParser.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.parserFor(TreeWalk.java:1286)
at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.reset(TreeWalk.java:699)
at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.forPath(TreeWalk.java:207)
at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.forPath(TreeWalk.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.forPath(TreeWalk.java:281)
at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$TreeWalkingSCMProbe.stat(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:1345)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowBranchProjectFactory$1.isHead(WorkflowBranchProjectFactory.java:74)
at jenkins.scm.api.trait.SCMSourceRequest.process(SCMSourceRequest.java:344)
at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$8.discoverBranches(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:557)
at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$8.run(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:535)
at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$8.run(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:521)
at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.doRetrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:352)
at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:521)
at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource._retrieve(SCMSource.java:355)
at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:265)
at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:634)
at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:276)
at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:978)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
```

[Tue Feb 27 10:30:56 UTC 2018] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 2.8 sec
FATAL: Failed to recompute children of GalleryProductService
java.io.EOFException: Short read of block.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.IO.readFully(IO.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.UnpackedObject.open(UnpackedObject.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openLooseObject(ObjectDirectory.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openLooseFromSelfOrAlternate(ObjectDirectory.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openObject(ObjectDirectory.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.CanonicalTreeParser.reset(CanonicalTreeParser.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.parserFor(TreeWalk.java:1286)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.reset(TreeWalk.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.forPath(TreeWalk.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.forPath(TreeWalk.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.forPath(TreeWalk.java:281)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$TreeWalkingSCMProbe.stat(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:1345)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowBranchProjectFactory$1.isHead(WorkflowBranchProjectFactory.java:74)
    at jenkins.scm.api.trait.SCMSourceRequest.process(SCMSourceRequest.java:344)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$8.discoverBranches(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:557)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$8.run(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:535)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$8.run(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:521)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.doRetrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:352)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:521)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource._retrieve(SCMSource.java:355)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:265)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:634)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:276)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:978)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was connecting to the Jenkins box and removing all the cached sources as they had become corrupt somehow. This didn't delete any data and just made the first run take about 10 seconds longer while it recreated new sources for each pipeline.